# How To Change Excel Calculation to Manual Before Workbook Does Calculation

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I am developing an add in for excel using vba.  Upon opening the spreadsheet, all the values are recalculated and this slows down the opening.  I've tried creating a Workbook_Open event that changes the application calculation from automatic to manual, but this event handler is executed after the calculations are done.  I also tried setting the calculation to manual before the spreadsheet closes, so that upon opening it next time it will be faster.  My problem with this though is that I feel it is invasive to the client.

Ideally what I would like to do is:

- When the spreadsheet opens get the user's current calculation setting and save it
- Change the calculation setting to manual so that the spreadsheet can open quickly
- Change the calculation setting back to the user's original setting

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: "My problem with this though is that I feel it is invasive to the client" - indeed. `Application.Calculation` is *application-level* state, and will be persisted when Excel is closed and then reopened - and then your client will not necessarily realize their sheets aren't calculating anymore, and will blame you when they realize what's going on.

Comment: Now this is an Excel add-in, so it opens along with Excel, when the splash screen is shown. How is "the worksheet" related to "the add-in", or how is the add-in any relevant? Is it the add-in openeing the workbook? If your calculations are inefficient, toggling calculation back to automatic will cause a significant delay *anyway*, so why not fix the actual problem instead of patching the symptoms?

Comment: See if [FastExcel](http://www.decisionmodels.com/fastexcel.htm) can help find out what the pain points are (IIRC there's a free demo/preview mode, otherwise it's a paid add-in). Charles Williams' blog also has a ton of resources for speeding up calculations.

Comment: Thanks for that resource @MathieuGuindon.  The add-in provides the functions that the worksheet is calculating.

Comment: See if your UDFs can be optimized, put them up on [codereview.se] =)

Answer (score 1):

I created 2 subs that I call when I need to do this, `Updates_Off` and `Updates_On`.  You will need to declare the variables `CalcMode`, `IterationMode`, and `Iterations` as public in your calling sub and this will only work if you turn updates back on before you exit.  If you can't do that, you will need to have some helper cells that store the values.

I have the `if CalcMode=xlCalculationManual` statements to warn me during development that I'm starting or ending in manual mode and I uncomment them when needed.

```
Public Sub Updates_Off()

' Turn off Screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Check what calculation mode is in effect and set current to manual
    CalcMode = Application.Calculation
'   If CalcMode = xlCalculationManual Then _
'       MsgBox "Starting mode is manual"

    IterationMode = Application.Iteration
    Iterations = Application.MaxIterations
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

End Sub


Public Sub Updates_On()

' Turn on Screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' Reset Calculation mode
    Application.Calculation = CalcMode
    Application.Iteration = IterationMode
    Application.MaxIterations = Iterations

'   If CalcMode = xlCalculationManual Then _
'       MsgBox "Reset to manual mode"

End Sub
```